# Inductive proof of symmetric identity of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, induction

I'm trying to proof the symmetric identity ${n \choose k} = {n \choose n-k}$ using induction.

I have the base case $${0 \choose 0} = 1 = {0 \choose 0-0}$$ for k=0 and $${0 \choose k} = 0 = {0 \choose n-k}$$ for every other k>0. My hypothesis is ${n \choose k} = {n \choose n-k}$ for any natural number, and I need to show that ${n+1 \choose k} = {n+1 \choose n-k+1}$. I used Pascal's Identity to show that $${n+1 \choose k} = {n \choose k} + {n \choose k-1}$$ which is equal to $${n! \over (n-k)!k!} = {n! \over (n-k+1)!(k-1)!} $$. At this point I don't know how to go on. I am generally not sure if I have done the induction steps correctly (I am a biology student), and would be very appreciating of any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more complicated than necessary, but your induction argument can be completed.  Starting from
$$\binom{n+1}{k} = \binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k-1}$$
apply the induction hypothesis to both terms on the right side (remember the induction hypothesis applies when the top is $n$ with *any* value on the bottom), which gives
$$\binom{n+1}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k} + \binom{n}{n-k+1}$$
Now apply the Pascal identity once more on the right side, to get what you want:
$$\binom{n+1}{k} = \binom{n+1}{n-k+1}.$$

Comment: Okay thank you for your helpful response! One more thing, is the base case with ${0 \choose k} = {0 \choose 0-k}$ for any k>0 correct?

Comment: @Quebec27 Yes.  In fact, for nonnegative $n$, if we define $\binom{n}{k} = 0$ for all integers $k<0$ or $k>n$, then Pascal's identity will still hold.  Just imagine extending Pascal's triangle with 0's indefinitely to the left and right on each row, and check that Pascal's identity still works.

Answer (score 2):

${n \choose k}= \frac{n!}{(n-k)! k!}=\frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!}={n\choose {n-k}}$

Did I misunderstand the purpose of this question?

Comment: I am trying to do an inductive proof for which I am asking for help.

Comment: @Quebec27 Well you can write the above sentence after you assume the induction hypothesis... I would say it is really a bad idea to write an inductive proof, since the induction hypothesis will not help you. Especially when you write the formula for ${n\choose k}$ out, the conclusion becomes obvious. In case you want some exercise, try to prove $1^2+2^2+\dots+n^2=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, by induction.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to see for myself how induction can be used in not so "convenient" cases. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As k99731 has pointed out, this result follows immediately from the definition.

Instead consider the following recurrence relation $A_{n,k}$ where we define $$ A_{n,k} = A_{n-1,k} + A_{n-1,k-1}$$ for all integers $n$ and integers $k$ such that $1\leq k\leq n$ and set the boundary conditions $A_{n,n}=A_{n,0}=1$ for every integer $n$.

Can you use induction to prove that $A_{n,k}=A_{n,n-k}$ for all $n,k$?

Hint: 
Let $S(n)$ be the statement that $A_{n,k}=A_{n,n-k}$ for all $1\leq k\leq n$. Can you prove that $S(n+1)$ will be true if $S(n)$ is true?